# Powershell script Compress-Archive partial failure

Tags: powershell

I have a script that includes:

```
try {
  Compress-Archive -Path "$($folder.FullName)\*" -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath $FullPath -Force
} catch {
  Write-Output "`nFailed to create zip"
}
```

Some of the files in the -Path folder are opened by another user, so Compress-Archive is unable to add them to the zip.  It reports this failure to stderr, however it doesn't throw an error.

Is there any way I can determine that the command has only partially succeeded without parsing stderr or re-opening the zip and comparing contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `Compress-Archive` is throwing a *non-terminating* error, which you cannot catch with `try` / `catch`.

However, if you add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the `Compress-Archive` call, the non-terminating error will be promoted to a *script-terminating error*, which *will* trigger your `catch` handler.

For an overview of PowerShell's complex error-handling rules, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).